# Oracle7:Merge data are same in many records to one record

Tags: oracle, merge

I would like to merge data are same in many records to one record.
From

```
       FO                 LINE  FLOOR   COLOR   SUM
    S4714EH02               EH  11F         AK  9
    S4714EH02               EH  11F         AK  18
    S4714EH02               EH  11F         FE  9
    S4714EH02               EH  11F         FE  18
    S4714EH02               EH  12F         AK  9
    S4714EH02               EH  12F         AK  18
    S4714EH02               EH  12F         FE  9
    S4714EH02               EH  12F         FE  18
```

To

```
  FO                   LINE FLOOR       COLOR   SUM
  S4714EH02             EH  11F         AK  9,18
  S4714EH02             EH  11F         FE  9,18
  S4714EH02             EH  12F         AK  9,18
  S4714EH02             EH  12F         FE  9,18
```

I know it can in sql server 2008 but I don't know it can make in oracle7 .
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Oracle 7? Really no way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 7 is a fine release of that database.  it introduced many new features, it performed well and obviously it remains exceedingly stable.  But it is long in the tooth and lacks many features available to us in more recent versions of the product.

For instance, all of the normal techniques we can use to aggregate values into a list only work in 9i or higher.  (Some may work in 8i, my mind is a little fuzzy here as it's been almost a decade since I worked with Oracle that old)

So do you have any options in Oracle 7?  The only one I can think of is to run a stored procedure as part of a reporting pre-process.  This stored procedure would loop round the rows you want to query, assemble rows which matched your desired output and then insert them into a different table.  This table would then service the actual query.

This is an extremely clunky workaround, and may not be viable in your situation.  But alas that is the cost of using legacy software.

Answer (score 2):

As already very well said by APC, this version is really old and lacks all kinds of functions to do string aggregation. I have worked with version 7 in the previous millenium though, and I think the next sequence should work in Oracle7. I could be wrong though, but obviously I can't check it.

```
SQL> create table t (fo,line,floor,color,sum)
  2  as
  3  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '11F', 'AK', 9 from dual union all
  4  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '11F', 'AK', 18 from dual union all
  5  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '11F', 'FE', 9 from dual union all
  6  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '11F', 'FE', 18 from dual union all
  7  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '12F', 'AK', 9 from dual union all
  8  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '12F', 'AK', 18 from dual union all
  9  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '12F', 'FE', 9 from dual union all
 10  select 'S4714EH02', 'EH', '12F', 'FE', 18 from dual
 11  /

Table created.

SQL> create function f
  2  ( p_fo    in t.fo%type
  3  , p_line  in t.line%type
  4  , p_floor in t.floor%type
  5  , p_color in t.color%type
  6  ) return varchar2
  7  is
  8    cursor c
  9    is
 10    select t.sum
 11      from t
 12     where t.fo = p_fo
 13       and t.line = p_line
 14       and t.floor = p_floor
 15       and t.color = p_color
 16     order by t.sum
 17    ;
 18    l_concatenated_sum varchar2(2000);
 19  begin
 20    for r in c
 21    loop
 22      l_concatenated_sum := l_concatenated_sum || ',' || to_char(r.sum);
 23    end loop;
 24    return substr(l_concatenated_sum,2);
 25  end f;
 26  /

Function created.

SQL> select fo
  2       , line
  3       , floor
  4       , color
  5       , f(fo,line,floor,color) sum
  6    from t
  7   group by fo
  8       , line
  9       , floor
 10       , color
 11  /

FO        LI FLO CO SUM
--------- -- --- -- --------------------
S4714EH02 EH 11F AK 9,18
S4714EH02 EH 11F FE 9,18
S4714EH02 EH 12F AK 9,18
S4714EH02 EH 12F FE 9,18

4 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: +1 I forgot we could call stored functions from SQL in Oracle 7.  Indeed it was a boss release!

Answer (score 0):

In the special case where you have only two records per distinct key -- as shown by your sample data -- you could do this:

```
SELECT fo, line, floor, color, MIN(sum) || ',' || MAX(sum)
  FROM theTable
  GROUP BY fo, line, floor, color;
```

But this can't be generalized to handle more than two values of `sum` per key.